# First div always on left, the remaining on right - positioning with css

Tags: css, html, position

I'm try to archieve the following:

[image]

with this code:

```
<div style="height: auto;">
     <div class="box">
        <div style="height: 300px;"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="box auto-height">
        asdasd
     </div>
    <div class="box auto-height">
        asdasd
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 45%;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

.auto-height {
    height: 50%;
}
```

The boxes will be looped and the first one is always bigger then the others. So I basically want the first one to be always on left, and the remaining ones to go on right.

I tried http://jsfiddle.net/59bwh/ but I can't get the height: 50% working.

Tho, the boxes on the right might be more then 2 (up to 5).

*PP: sorry for the title (I searched that on google, couldn't find anything, someone like me might search the same, so I wrote this as title). I will edit it if you got any suggestions.*

Comment: For css, the parent of the div must have an EXPLICIT height.  Otherwise you must use javascript/jquery.

Comment: I prefer to not, but if I don't figure out any other solution I will. How about something with tables? I think it's doable, but I have no idea how to do it. Can you suggest a JS solution?

Comment: One way with Jquery http://jsfiddle.net/59bwh/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about using a table in the comments...

http://jsfiddle.net/59bwh/12/

```
<table style="width:90%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="height: 300px;">Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use absolute positioning.

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.box {
    width: 45%;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid red;
/*    float: left; */
}
.fixd {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
}
.fixd + .fixd {
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hezvm/).

Important is definition of property `position: relative;` for parent element. First element defines height of the parent. Second and third element are positioned absolutely inside then parent. You can define height of elements by `top` and `bottom` properties.

If number of right side elements is not fixed you have to compute size by JavaScript.

The simplest JavaScript should be something like this:

```
$('.fixd').css('height', $('.fixd').parent().innerHeight() / $('.fixd').size());
```

In real app you have to do some correction (paddings, margins, borders). Then script for your fiddle should be something like this

```
var height = $('.fixd').parent().innerHeight(),
    count = $('.fixd').size(),
    boxSize = 0;

// Correction of borders and margin-top size
height = height - count * 2 - (count-1) * 10;
boxSize = Math.floor(height/count);

// set computed size
$('.fixd').css('height', boxSize)
   .first().css('margin-top', 0);

// fix last element (it is because of rounding floating numbers)
$('.fixd').last().css('height', height-(count-1)*boxSize);
```

Complete fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hezvm/3/)

Comment: Problem -here is *the boxes on the right might be more then 2 (up to 5).*

Comment: Then you need write some JavaScript function to compute correct height of right side elements.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question per say, but this could be very useful for you.

http://css-tricks.com/rotating-feature-boxes/

If you don't want to use a plugin, try this...

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="left">
          <div class="box">
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="right">
          <div class="box-auto-height">
          </div>
          <div class="box-auto-height">
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#container{
width:100%;
margin:auto;
display:block;
height:100%;
}

.left{
width:50%;
height:100%;
padding:10px;
float:left;
}

.right{
width:50%;
height:100%;
padding:10px;
float:left;
}

.box-auto-height{
width:100%;
height:50%;
}

div img{
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/59bwh/9/

```
.box {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fixd1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:50%;
}
.fixd2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}



<div style="position:relative">
    <div class="box">
        <div style="height: 400px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box fixd1">
        asdasd
    </div>
    <div class="box fixd2">
        asdasd
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

50% height is derived from the parent, not sibling.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   your boxes goes here
</div>
```

then the CSS would be

```
.wrapper { height: 300px }
.box { height: 100% }
.auto-height { height: 50% }
```

Comment: The problem is that I place a image in the first box and I don't know its size (it's different every time) and the image expands the div depending on its height.

Comment: I don't think the OP can set a fixed height on the parent since the images will vary every time.